# Column X of relation Y contains null values

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

When inserting first admin into my database I get this error message and don't know how to solve it:

```
[Nest] 13803   - 04/27/2021, 23:03:02   [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (6)... +3176ms
QueryFailedError: column "name" of relation "admin" contains null values
```

Other tables work just fine so far and without errors.

Column `name` in `admin` table is not null it contains value:
[image: admin table]

Register service:

```
async register(registerInput: RegisterInput): Promise<void> {
    const { key, name, password, email } = registerInput;

    const hashedKey = createHash('sha256')
      .update(key)
      .digest('hex');

    const invite = await this.invitesRepository.findOne({ key: hashedKey });

    if (!invite) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }

    const newAdmin = await this.adminsRepository.create({
      name,
      password,
      email,
    });
    await this.adminsRepository.save(newAdmin);

    await this.invitesRepository.delete({ id: invite.id });
  }
```

Comment: what is the value of the prop `name` in `registerInput`?

Comment: I entered "John Doe" as displayed in table, but whatever value I input and however many admins I add the error doesn't go away.

Comment: Can you update the question with the related entity classes and the connection options you pass to connect to the database?

Comment: Also, try to delete your `dist` directory, rebuild the code and try again

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I deleted `dist` directory and rebuilt the code. This solved the issue.

Comment: This still works in 2022. I don't know why it's necessary, though. Added `rm -rf dist` in the `package.json` script for convenience.